# Passing a Parameter to Javascript Function for ajax in mvc

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, parameters

I have a problem that I cannot handle. I have a  ASP.NET MVC application. It's purpose is to listing items inside. These items are project activity with financial report of it. At the view, users suppose to view the financial information of the project activity and edit some values. Here is the view:

```
@model IEnumerable<DKMPPIB.Presentation.ViewModelKlasor.VarlikKlasoru.ProjectActivityFinancialReportViewModel>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Region)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.City)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ProjectName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FieldName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ProjectActivityName)
        </th>           
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>     
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Region)
            </td>      
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.City)
            </td> 
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProjectName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FieldName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProjectActivityName)
            </td>            
            <td>
                <a onclick="readTender()" >
                    <img src='@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/glyphicons_free/glyphicons-342-briefcase.png")' />
                </a>                    
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href='@Url.Action("MyAction", "MyController")'>
                    <img src='@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/glyphicons_free/glyphicons-459-money.png")' />
                </a>
            </td>    
            @*Take attention to that line. I embed the ProjectActivityId here.*@                
            <td style="visibility:hidden" id="satirProjeFaaliyetId">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProjectActivityId)</td> 

        </tr>        
    }

</table>


<div id="tender-message" title="Tender Information" style="visibility:hidden">
    <p>
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-check" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 50px 0;"></span>
        Here is your tender detail: 
    </p>
    <p>
        Currently using <b>36% of your budget </b>.
    </p>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">


    function readTender(){

    //I will make an ajax call to get tender information. I need ProjectActivityId for this.
        alert("read tender");
        //var projectActivityId = $('#ProjectActivityId').find(":selected").val();
        //console.log(bolgeDropdownId);

        //$.ajax({
        //    type: "POST",
        //    url: '/Erp/GetTenderInformation',
        //    data: "{ProjectActivityId :'" + projectActivityId + "'}",
        //    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        //    dataType: "json",
        //    success: successFunc,
        //    error: errorFunc
        //});
    }

</script>
```

As mentioned above, the javascript function *readTender* needs *projectActivityId* as an input to read tender information. I write *projectActivityId* to the last td tag of view. How can I pass *projectActivityId* to *readTender*()?

Here is the content of *ProjectActivityFinancialReportViewModel*:

```
 public class ProjectActivityFinancialReportViewModel
    {
        private ProjectActivityLocationViewModel _projectActivityLocationVM;
        private ProjectActivityViewModel _projectActivityVM;

        [Display(Name = "Region")]
        public string Region
        {
            get
            {
                if (this._projeFaaliyetKonumVM == null)
                    return string.Empty;
                else
                    return this._projectActivityLocationVM.RegionName;
            }

        }

        [Display(Name = "City")]
        public string City
        {
            get
            {
                if (this._projectActivityLocationVM == null)
                    return string.Empty;
                else
                    return this._projectActivityLocationVM.CityName;
            }

        }     

        [Display(Name = "Field Name")]
        public string FieldName
        {
            get
            {
                if (this._projectActivityLocationVM == null || this._projectActivityLocationVM.LocationVm != null)
                    return string.Empty;
                else
                    return this._projectActivityLocationVM.LocationVm.Name;
            }

        }       

        [Display(Name = "Project Activity Name")]
        public string ProjectActivityName
        {
            get
            {
                if (this._projectActivityVM == null)
                    return string.Empty;
                else
                    return this._projectActivityVM.ActivityVM.Name;
            }
        }

        [Display(Name = "Project Name")]
        public string ProjectName
        {
            get
            {
                if (this._projectActivityVM == null)
                    return string.Empty;
                else
                    return this._projectActivityVM.ProjectVM.Name;
            }
        }

        public int ProjectActivityId
        {
            get
            {
                if (this._projectActivityVM == null || this._projectActivityVM.Id == null)
                    return int.MinValue;
                else
                {
                    int id = this._projectActivityVM.Id ?? int.MinValue;
                    return id;
                }                    
            }

        }

        public TenderViewModel TenderVM
        {
            get
            {
                if (this._projectActivityVM == null)
                    return null;
                else
                    return this._projectActivityVM.TenderVM;
            }
        }

        public ProjeFaaliyetMaliRaporveProjeFaaliyetViewModel()
        {
            this._projectActivityLocationVM = null;
            this._projectActivityVM = null;           
        }

    }
```

Comment: There are numerous ways. e.g. add it as a `data-id="@item.ProjectActivityId"` attribute and read it in the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle click event for each row.
I suppose "selection" is handled by "click" over the row.
You can do that in this way:

1. Change your javascript function:

`function readTender(projectActivityId) {
  ...
}`

2. Change your tr inside the foreach:

`<tr onclick="javascript:readTender(@item.ProjectActivityId)">;
  ...
<tr>`

Answer (score 0):

```
<td style="visibility:hidden" id="satirProjeFaaliyetId">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProjectActivityId)</td>
```

Problem here is, that you try to find an element by an id that is not present:

```
$('#ProjectActivityId').find(":selected").val();
```

So change the top line to the following:

```
<td style="visibility:hidden;" id="ProjectActivityId">@item.ProjectActivityId</td>
```

and the line in your js-code to

```
$('#ProjectActivityId').val();
```

Comment: The code is originally in Turkish, and I convert it to English in order for understanding. I forget to change it.